# Mocking multiple collaborators with Groovy MockFor or StubFor

Tags: unit-testing, groovy

I am learning how to write unit tests with Groovy. I'm familiar with both EasyMock and Mockito but thought I'd try the pure Groovy way. The class I want to test has multiple collaborators I need to mock. The [examples](http://groovy-lang.org/testing.html) for MockFor demonstrate `mock.use`, but don't indicate how to employ more than one mock. So, I extended the Family/Person example to include a Pet and wrote a sample test for a method needing both a Person and a Pet. The only way I found to apply both a Person mock and a Pet mock was to nest `mock.use` closures as shown below.

This works (produces a JUnit green bar), but I'm wondering if it's the right/best way to do it? It could get ugly fast if I have to mock several collaborators in this fashion - nesting N levels deep. Ugh.

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import org.junit.Test

class FamilyTest {
  @Test
  void testCuddle() {
    def kidMock = new MockFor(Person)
    kidMock.demand.getFirst {'Kid'}

    kidMock.use {
      def catMock = new MockFor(Pet)
      catMock.demand.getName {'Cat'}
      catMock.use {
        def family = new Family(kid:new Person(), cat:new Pet())
        assert family.cuddle() == 'Kid hugs Cat'
      }
      catMock.expect.verify()
    }
    kidMock.expect.verify()
  }

  class Person {
    String first, last
  }

  class Pet {
    String name
  }

  class Family {
    Person kid
    Pet cat

    // method under test
    def cuddle() { "$kid.first hugs $cat.name" }
  }
}
```

Edit: The below works, but the verify methods don't match the documentation, which say to use `mock.expect.verify()`. When I try the latter, I get an exception "expected 1 call, got 0".

Again I wonder - it works, but is it the right/preferred/best way?

```
@Test
void testCuddle2() {
    def kidMock = new MockFor(Person)
    kidMock.demand.with {getFirst {'Kid'}}
    def catMock = new MockFor(Pet)
    catMock.demand.with {getName {'Cat'}}

    def kidProxy = kidMock.proxyInstance();
    def catProxy = catMock.proxyInstance();

    def family = new Family(kid:kidProxy, cat:catProxy)
    assert family.cuddle() == 'Kid hugs Cat'

    kidMock.verify(kidProxy)
    catMock.verify(catProxy)
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and I don't want to chain stub.use {} calls!